# I am trying to build an ant project but my build compilation is getting failed

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have correctly pointed it to jdk in eclipse as well as checked the global entries then also I am getting error as :-

```
    [javac]   childRolesMap=record.childRolesData.get("Roles").toArray(new Map[0]);                                                                             
    [javac]   required: Map<String,Object>[]
    [javac]   found:    Map[]
BUILD FAILED
C:\ABC\ABCConnector\build.xml:37: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is my build.xml snippet where it redirects on clicking the complied failed link, it points to the line where I have given the value of source and target.

```
  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="classes"/>
   <!-- <property file="../build.properties"/> -->
    <javac destdir="classes" srcdir="src" classpathref="classpath" debug="on" nowarn="on"
        includeantruntime="false" target="1.8" source="1.8">
      <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
      <compilerarg value="-Xlint:-path"/>
    </javac>
```

Please let me know if you have any idea on how to solve this.

Comment: The issue is in your java code, not in ant script.

Comment: As @Rao says, the problem is with the Java compile. It's possible that the compile is failing because the environment ant is creating is wrong. But if I were you, I would get the compile working manually outside of ant and then see what changes you need in your ant script to get it working there.